# Referencing sheets with spaces

Tags: excel, vba, notation

I am having an issue with referencing the sheet name  through `=Branded!$A$1` Notation in VBA. For a while I have passed in simple sheet names like:

```
Dim SheetName As String
SheetName = "Pizza"
("=" & SheetName & "!$A$1")
```

This has worked fine, but recently I passed in "Tier 1" and of course this notation broke. Is there any fix or workaround for this? It Think it's because of the space, the number or both....

Comment: You are declaring SheetName as an Integer and assigning a string to it. This code triggers an error.

Comment: Sheet names with spaces require single-quotes. Create one, and then refer to a cell in it from another sheet and you'll see the correct format with the name surrounded by single-quotes.

Answer (score 3):

varocarbas is right, if you declare "As Integer" it means you will put numbers not text. Just change "As Integer" to "As String" and it should look something like this:

```
Sub Reference()

Dim SheetName As String
SheetName = "Pizza 1"
Range("A1").Value = "='" & SheetName & "'!A1"

End Sub
```

Comment: @user2250964 - then update your question with your *actual* code

Comment: I just don't know what this code stands for?
    ("=" & SheetName & "!$A$1") Could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

no idea what your code is meant to do but if you have spaces in a sheet name (or a name that looks like a date) you have to enclose it in single quotes

```
"='" & SheetName & "'!$A$1"
```